# How to Roll Back ESXi Patch/Upgrades?

Tags: vmware, putty, vsphere, esxi, hypervisor

Using vSphere Update Manager I've installed some updates and patches onto my host, however I have an issue with it picking up a datastore now so I want to roll back these changes to see if that fixes the issue.

From my research I understand that you can't uninstall these patches and you have to revert back to a previous ESXi version. I'm attempting to do this following the steps here: https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1033604

However it does not give reference on how to access the Console for the Host. I can't find a way to access it in vSphere, but found a way by downloading putty and running the DCUI command.

**The problem I have is that it says Reboot and then:**

**When the Hypervisor progress bar starts loading, press Shift+R.**

**However when I reboot putty loses connection to the host (presumably because it is rebooting) so I never get to see the boot up screen and Hypervisor progress bar to press Shift+R.**

Am I missing something simple here? Server is Dell running ESXi 5.5. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] or [sf] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Dell ilo interface shall provide you the recover(<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) while rebooting and hence rollback option.

The default credentials for dell ilo would be,
username : root
pwd : calvin

The steps to achieve this would be as follow,

1. Get ur ILO link, please see if below link is useful to you in this regard.

https://www.dell.com/community/Systems-Management/How-to-get-the-DRAC-IP-address-from-the-localhost/td-p/2374426

otherway would be ping your server FQDN and it would return the ILO IP.

2. Once you find ilo url or IP, login to it using above mentioned default login credentials(root/calvin).
3. Now, in ILO interface find the option to launch the console (server -> Virtual console preview -> Launch).
4. Save the JNLP file and run it.
5. Further, Press <kbd>F12</kbd> for "Shout down /restart"

Here onward I believe you will get it.

Thanks,
Manjunath.